# Why am I receiving this error message when browsing nvidia.com?

Tags: tls, certificates

I'm receiving this randomly when I try to visit nvidia.com.  I can either not reach the site at all with a 504 error, or I get this screen.

What does it mean, and what is the cause?

[image: nvidia.com]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [report by SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=nvidia.com):

> Chain issues  Incomplete

This is a misconfiguration of the server: it is not sending the full certificate chain up to (but not including) the root certificate but instead only sends the leaf certificate. Specifically it is missing the intermediate certificate for RapidSSL TLS RSA CA G1. Without knowledge of the intermediate certificates the browser can not verify the certificate chain up to the locally trusted root CA - which results in the error you see.

While desktop browsers often successfully work around this configuration issues this is not successful in all cases.

Comment: So it's a temporary error that everyone experiences who try to visit, and also unexpected given that it's NVidia and their main website? It's been like this for 2 or 3 days if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @BigTuna The site hosting the driver downloads (where MitM attacks would be a problem) seems ok (www.geforce.com and us.download.nvidia.com). The TLS configuration in nvidia.com is incompetent. Maybe only that domain is under the direct control of the marketing department, maybe it's just big company IT being incompetent.

Comment: @BigTuna: Yes, even big web sites sometimes have broken configurations. And given that browsers often (but not always) successfully work around such problems they might not even realize that they have these problems. And given that the site currently gets a rating of F and missing intermediate certificates is just one of their problems (others are SSLv3, POODLE, no forward secrecy with common browsers), my guess is that the ones managing the site are either incompetent or heavily understaffed.

Comment: @BigTuna: also note that nvidia.com is just redirecting to www.nivida.com which then has a much better configuration (grade A).